# Отображение нескольких подсказок на одном окне

Tags: c#, wpf

Если создать пару ToolTip'ов, привязать их к 2 разным контролам и отобразить используя IsOpen, второй ToolTip ни за что не закроется... Даже если сделать таймер по его закрытию используя то же свойство.

Почему так происходит и как решить проблему? Можно ли убить этот ToolTip когда потребуется (юзер сменит фокус или таймер истечёт)?

P.S.: Желательно без WinApi обойтись.

Comment: А если заменить Tooltip на Popup? У них-то точно можно управлять видимостью.

Comment: Ну Popup не поможет.
Он вообще не так как ToolTip себя ведёт... Коснись окна, чтобы потащить - Popup исчезнет обработав события, которые предназначены окну (вообще не должен он исчезать).

Comment: Ну вроде ж ToolTip внутри использует Popup? Можно по идее убрать непрозрачность IsHitTestVisible и вернуть фокус.

Comment: Не совсем понял как вы предлагаете это реализовать.

IsHitTestVisible в false что ли?

Comment: Ну да. Я сейчас не могу попробовать, но по идее должно работать?

Comment: Не работает это.

Comment: Да и не в насильственном закрытии дело.
Нужно чтобы он сам закрывался при клике на окне, при перетаскивании окна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решение данной проблемы достаточно уяснить принципы поведения Popup, т.к. ToolTip полностью построен на нём.
Когда отображается первая подсказка, она "съедает" все щелчки по окну. Второму, соответственно, ничего не остаётся и он просто виснет на месте.
Я предлагаю решение через объект окна. Точнее, через маршрутизируемые события окна: обрабатываем закрытие каждого ToolTip и вызываем, например, PreviewMouseDown для окна (через Raise event); подписываемся на то же событие окна и в обработчике закрываем подсказку.

Код (делаем так для каждого ToolTip):

```
Window wnd = Window.GetWindow(this);
MyToolTip.Closed += (s, e) => {
MouseButtonEventArgs args = new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Right);
args.RoutedEvent = PreviewMouseDownEvent;
args.Source = wnd;
RaiseEvent(args);
};

wnd.PreviewMouseDown += (s, e) => MyToolTip.IsOpen = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня прекрасно работает решение с `Popup`. Пришлось, правда, стащить дополнительную функцию [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2466030/276994).

Код:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        Title="Тест" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid TextBlock.FontSize="36">
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="B1">
            Привет
        </Button>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="B2">
            Пока
        </Button>
        <Popup StaysOpen="True" IsOpen="True" VerticalOffset="-15" HorizontalOffset="25"
               Name="P1" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=B1}">
            <TextBlock Background="LightCyan">Привет</TextBlock>
        </Popup>
        <Popup StaysOpen="True" IsOpen="True" VerticalOffset="-15" HorizontalOffset="25"
               Name="P2" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=B2}">
            <TextBlock Background="LightCyan">Пока</TextBlock>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

И код:

```
static class PopupHelper
{
    public static void SetupPopup(Popup popup, Window window)
    {
        window.LocationChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var offset = popup.HorizontalOffset;
            popup.HorizontalOffset = offset + 0.001;
            popup.HorizontalOffset = offset;
        };
    }
}
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PopupHelper.SetupPopup(P1, this);
        PopupHelper.SetupPopup(P2, this);
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дак при клике по окну (и перетаскивании) это исчезать должно.
Поведение должно быть как у ToolTip.

Comment: Привязка к окну меня так же не устраивает. Привязка должна быть к контролам со смещением по горизонтали и вертикали.

UPD: хотя это ладно. Можно и к контролу так же сделать, вместо окна.

Comment: Да и следование за окном есть плохо. Не должно быть никаких функций по движению. Я же говорю, поведение как у ToolTip.

Comment: @D.Stark: (1) А при каких условиях появляться? Формулируйте желательное поведение полностью. (2) Привязка, если вы внимательно посмотрите в код, к Button'ам. (3) Вы хотите, чтобы при движении окна тултипы оставались на месте? Попробуйте в коде не вызывать `PopupHelper.SetupPopup`, и увидите, как это выглядит. Сразу скажу — не очень.

Comment: Давайте я отвечу на собственный вопрос сам (так как уже разобрался давно) и вы посмотрите что я хотел.
Благодарю за то, что потратили на мою проблему своё время)